# Disable unrolling of a particular loop in GCC

Tags: gcc, optimization, pragma, loop-unrolling

I have the following 4x4 matrix-vector multiply code:

```
double const __restrict__ a[16];
double const __restrict__ x[4];
double       __restrict__ y[4];

//#pragma GCC unroll 1 - does not work either
#pragma GCC nounroll
for ( int j = 0; j < 4; ++j )
{
    double const* __restrict__ aj = a + j * 4;
    double const xj = x[j];

    #pragma GCC ivdep
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
    {
        y[i] += aj[i] * xj;
    }
}
```

I compile with `-O3 -mavx` flags. The inner loop is vectorized (single FMAD). However, gcc (7.2) keeps unrolling the outer loop 4 times, unless I use `-O2` or lower optimization.

Is there a way to override `-O3` unrolling of a particular loop?

NB. Similar `#pragma nounroll` works if I use Intel icc.

Comment: `#pragma GCC unroll n` works in GCC 8.x - but only to some extent - as far as I can see it is more a hint than strict requirement (how many times it should be unrolled).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, `#pragma GCC unroll 1` is supposed to work, if you place it just so. If it doesn't then you should submit a bug report.

Alternatively, you can use a function attribute to set optimizations, I think:

```
void myfn () __attribute__((optimize("no-unroll-loops")));
```

Comment: It does not, I just rechecked. `#pragma GCC unroll 0` should also do it according to docs, but it does not.

Answer (score 1):

For concise functions
sans full and partial loop unrolling
when required
the following function attribute
please try.

```
__attribute__((optimize("Os")))
```